Why are marginals from scipy.linprog(method='highs') -0.?
Please find code, output, and package versions below.
I was under the impression that the r.eqlin.marginals array returned from scipy.optimize.linprog represents how much the cost function changes with respect to a small change in the equality constraints. In my example I have two equality constraints, and I would expect the marginals for both constraints to be 1. However, the marginal of the first constraint becomes -0. and the marginal for the second constraint becomes 1. It's not obvious to me why this happens and would appreciate any help on the matter. When manually increasing the value of b_eq[0], the value of the cost function increases, so if my interpretation of what the marginals represents, it seems strange that r.eqlin.marginals[0] becomes -0..
Code
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A_eq = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1]])

b_eq = np.array([10, 10])

c = np.array([1, 1, 1])

r = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq)

print(r)

Output
           con: array([0., 0.])
 crossover_nit: 0
         eqlin:  marginals: array([-0.,  1.])
                  residual: array([0., 0.])
           fun: 10.0
       ineqlin:  marginals: array([], dtype=float64)
                  residual: array([], dtype=float64)
         lower:  marginals: array([1., 0., 0.])
                  residual: array([ 0., 10., -0.])
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)'
           nit: 0
         slack: array([], dtype=float64)
        status: 0
       success: True
         upper:  marginals: array([0., 0., 0.])
                  residual: array([inf, inf, inf])
             x: array([ 0., 10., -0.])

Package versions
numpy: 1.24.4
scipy: 1.9.0


The behaviour you expect is not the case if the solution to the problem is degenerate, as my explanation of your observations will demonstrate.
In the solution [x, y, z] of your problem y=10 is basic, and the other basic variable (extracted directly from HiGHS, but invisible to SciPy users?) is z=0. Since it's non-positive, the solution is degenerate. If the RHS of the first equation is 10+d, then the solution is x=0, y=10+d, z=-d. Hence the marginal values for the equations are not valid for d>0, otherwise z would be negative.

By symmetry of the LP, there is also an optimal basis with y=10 basic and x basic. In this case, the marginals for the equations are [1, 0]. If the RHS of the first equation is 10+d, then the solution is x=d, y=10, z=0. Now the marginal values for the equations are valid for d>0, since x becomes positive, and you get the objective change (increase of d) that you expect.

Returning to the solution given by the solver, if the limiting value d=0 is used to define a basis change in which z becomes nonbasic, then x will become basic, giving the second basic solution identified. Now the RHS of the first equation can be increased. However, few solvers (if any) give this "parametric" marginal information.
In case you're wondering, "SparseRunner" is the HiGHS team leader - Julian Hall

Finally, in response to "I would expect the marginals for both constraints to be 1.", there is no optimal basis for which this happens. The basis containing [x, z] has marginals [1, 1] for the equations, but the marginal for the nonbasic variable (y) is [-1] so the basis is not optimal. Increasing y from zero, it can reach 10 and one of x or z becomes nonbasic, yielding one of the two optimal bases above.
